# With JOLT need to Transform JSON object with If Then Else Condition

Tags: json, jolt

Below is my Input Json

```json
[
  {
    "correlationId": "12345",
    "payloadFormat": "Money",
    "payload": {
      "DE35": "123654ABC54678",
      "DE45": "898454PQR54678"
    }
  }
]
```

I need to Trnsaform this json in such a way if DE35 has value say of substring 6-9 then take DE35 value in Transform Json, if DE35 do not have value then Take DE45 value in transform Json.

So output will be if DE35 Available then

```json
[ {
  "COR_ID" : "12345",
  "payloadFormat" : "Money",
  "EXT_SERV_CD":"ABC"
} ]
```

if DE35 is not available then the output should be

```json
[ {
  "COR_ID" : "12345",
  "payloadFormat" : "Money",
  "EXT_SERV_CD":"PQR"
} ]
```

I am using Below JOLT spec to do Transformation but it is not working.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&",
        "payload": {
          "DE|DE35": "&2.payload.TMPDE35"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "DE35Val": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE35), 6, 9)"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "&",
        "payload": {
          "DE|DE45": "&2.payload.TMPDE45"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "DE45Val": "=substring(@(1,TMPDE45), 6, 9)"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "correlationId": "[&1].COR_ID",
        "payloadFormat": "[&1].payloadFormat",
        "payload": {
          "DE35Val": {
            "ABC": {
              "DE35Val": "[#3].payload.EXT_SERV_CD"
            },
            "false": {
              "DE45Val": "[#3].payload.EXT_SERV_CD"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Please suggest where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This spec should work for you

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "TmpDE35": "=substring(@(1,payload.DE35), 6, 9)",
        "TmpDE45": "=substring(@(1,payload.DE45), 6, 9)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Tmp35_45": "=concat(@(1,TmpDE35), @(1,TmpDE45))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "EXT_SERV_CD": "=substring(@(1,Tmp35_45), 0, 3)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "Tmp*": null,
        "payload": null
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The solution idea:

1. Move the substrings of the `DE35`, `DE45` fields to the `TmpDE35`, `TmpDE45`
2. Concatenate `TmpDE35`, `TMPDE45` and store it in the `Tmp35_45`. If `TmpE35` is empty then the first 3 characters will come from `TmpDE45`
3. Get the substring `Tmp35_45`
4. Clean up, shift

Comment: You are gr8 Kasptom, its awesome , this is the solution some how I am looking and missing, once again that a lots for the quick support